# Runtime determination of base class

Tags: java, android, inheritance, composition, base-class

I have two OS dependent base classes - Class A and Class B in the form of separate jars.

Before N OS, the behavior was --> Class C extends Class A.

Now, the behavior that is required is:

Till Android M: Class C extends Class A.

For Android N and above: Class C extends Class B.

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Thanks PM..I know what composition is but I am not sure how to use that for this situation. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Can you come up with a common interface between the two and write an adapter between said interface and each of your base classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Come up with a common interface that covers the functionality that `A` and `B` provide, and write adapters between this interface and the two said classes.  Then compose the appropriate adapter into your `C` class.

Comment: @iHavADoubt This answer is your best option. Inheritance in Java is static and can't depend on the OS.

Comment: Thanks. Works great! I was able to use this solution to accomplish my objective.